# Sony SmartEyeGlass and face recognition

Tags: camera, face-recognition, sony-smarteyeglass

basic question -
Does Sony smarteyeglass support face recognition API through the camera (native or 3rd party)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The SmartEyeglass SDK is a regular android app so it supports everything that native android supports. If you wanted to implement a face recognition sample you can start with the "SampleCameraExtension" sample and grab the JPEG stream from the glasses and run a face recognition API on each image returned.